# How to transpose a data frame

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, pivot, transpose

I have a data frame that looks like this -

```
      project name       comment1     comment2           comment3      comment4
Row1           NY       Not good    somewhat ok         ridiculous  satisfactory
Row2           LA   job well done     standard   under performance      standard
```

How do I convert it like below ?

```
     project name            comment
Row1           NY           Not good
Row2           NY        Somewhat Ok
Row3           NY         ridiculous
Row4           NY       satisfactory
Row5           LA      job well done
Row6           LA           standard
Row7           LA  under performance
Row8           LA           standard
```

This is a transpose like operation but only comment1 to comment4 are transposed. In SAS this can be done creating array. But I dont know how will I approach the problem in python. Has anybody done this before ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `melt`:

```
df.melt(id_vars='project name', value_name='comment').drop('variable', axis=1)\
  .sort_values(by='project name')
```

Output:

```
  project name            comment
1           LA      job well done
3           LA           standard
5           LA  under performance
7           LA           standard
0           NY           Not good
2           NY        somewhat ok
4           NY         ridiculous
6           NY       satisfactory
```

Comment: Hey, that's helpful. But I need the same project names to be together, like all the 'NY' should be together and all the 'LA' should be together.

Comment: Use sort_values(by='project_name') at the end of that statement.

Comment: Not sure if I should ask a new question for this: what if I have three additional variables review1, review2, review3 and want to put them into a 'review' column just like 'comment' ? I dont think melt can handle that, can it ?

Comment: You are going to have to use a really weird function [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html#pandas-wide-to-long) or you can melt twice and merge/join the two dataframes on index.